# kendoui DateTimePicker minimum date 0001-01-01

Tags: datetime, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I would like to set the minimum date of a kendoui `DateTimePicker` to `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z`. I use the following piece of code:

```
<input id="datetimepicker" />

<script>
    $("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
      min: new Date("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z")
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately the calendar doesn't show dates before `01/01/1901`. If I set the minimum to `new Date("0100-01-01T00:00:00Z")`, the calendar shows date from the year 100 (as expected).

How can I get the calendar to show dates from 0001-01-01?

Comment: You can't show dates late than 01/01/1900 is `Kendo.DateTimePicker`, is an framework limitation.

Comment: @MarcoPalma By default the minimum date the control allows is 1900, but you can change the minimum to something lower than 1900. For instance if you set year 100, it works great.